# How to keep Google maps Zoom level?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a asp website and it contains a street address field which will auto complete from Google maps.Near the textbox field there is a image button.A pop up window will show google maps with marker of the place in street address field when we click the button.Currently my zoom level is 15.The user may zoom in the map and close the window.Then he may return back to map again.Currently the zoom level will return to 15 again.How can i keep the zoom level selected by user?

OnClientClick of imagebutton.

```
             function SetStreet() {
                    $('#map-canvas').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        if (checkPlace == "placeselected") {
                            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                            map.setZoom(15);
                            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                            marker.setVisible(true);                                
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what your architecture is and how you want to store this data. You may simply want to store the user details and map settings in your database or have it stored in a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

This will not done by simply `javascript`, I think you should store the `user's map settings` in `database` by using [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax). So, next time when the `user` see the `map` then he will his `last updated settings`.

Comment: My user is a staff who entry the details of customers and the street address field value changes regularly.